# Using Firebug to show DOM Hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, firebug

I am currently using FireBug to debug my javascript and HTML code. I was wondering if anyone knows of a feature where I can mouseover my generated web-page and it will display the DOM hierarchy of where my mouse is currently located. So if I have nested floating div elements. And I mouseover one of the divs, it will show the ID of that div, the id of its parent, the id of its parent's parent etc.

Comment: Why not make your own with jQuery or something similar?

Comment: FireBug already does that. Click on HTML then click the icon of an arrow pointing at a box, then click anywhere on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't clicking the inspect button (second from the top-left on Firebug) do something a lot like that?
[image: Inspect Button]

Comment: What tool did you use to create your screenshot?  I like the border, drop shadow, and the curvy dashed arrow.  It looks nice, and clearly was easy - it didn't take you very long.

Comment: I found it on Google Images ;-)

Answer (score 1):

google chrome, right click and select 'inspect element'. It brings up the dom tree with the clicked on element highlighted

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of this is what you are looking for. When you rightclick and use "Inspect Element", you will see the DOM and everything else in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Right click, Inspect Element also works in Firefox / Firebug

You can also use F12, Ctrl + B in IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

This FireFox extension does exactly that

[Web Developer Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

You can set it to outline elements as you hover over them and it will display their info, as well as their position in the dom tree.